# How to add a simple horizontal line at Y value of JFreeChart TimeSeries

Tags: java, time-series, jfreechart, simpledateformat, timeserieschart

I have created a chart like so:

[image]

Main code used for adding and/or updating information:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateAsStringToParse);
Second second = new Second(date);
myInfo.getSeries().addOrUpdate(second, maxValue); // maxValue is an Integer
```

And for creation of actual chart:

```
final XYDataset dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection(myInfo.getSeries());
JFreeChart timechart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(myInfo.getName()
    + " HPS", "", "HPS", dataset, false, false, false);
```

I would like to simply add an horizontal line (parallel to X (time) axis) at a constant value, let's say 10,000. So the graph will look something like so:

[image]

**What would be the easiest (most correct) way to achieve this with my code?**

Comment: Maybe `XYLineAnnotation`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20XYLineAnnotation), with a heavy `Stroke`?

Comment: @trashgod that is a fantastic suggestion, but when I try `timechart.getXYPlot().addAnnotation(new XYLineAnnotation(0, 1.5, 100000, 1.5));` what should be the `x1, y1, x2, y2` values though to get it across the chart like in my picture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want an [`XYLineAnnotation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYLineAnnotation.html), but the coordinates for a [`TimeSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeries.html) may be troublesome. Starting from [`TimeSeriesChartDemo1`](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo2/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.java), I made the following changes to get the chart shown.

1. First, we need the `x` value for the first and last `RegularTimePeriod` in the `TimeSeries`.

   ```
    long x1, x2;
    …
    x1 = s1.getTimePeriod(0).getFirstMillisecond();
    x2 = s1.getNextTimePeriod().getLastMillisecond();
   ```
2. Then, the constant `y` value is easy; I chose 140.

   ```
    double y = 140;
   ```

   Alternatively, you can derive a value from your `TimeSeries`, for example.

   ```
    double y = s1.getMinY() + ((s1.getMaxY() - s1.getMinY()) / 2);
   ```
3. Finally, we construct the annotation and add it to the plot.

   ```
    XYLineAnnotation line = new XYLineAnnotation(
        x1, y, x2, y, new BasicStroke(2.0f), Color.black);
    plot.addAnnotation(line);
   ```

[image]