# How to add horizontal value marker on Bar Chart in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, charts, scenebuilder

What is the best and simplese way to add horizontal line on my Bar chart in JavaFX. I want make something like on image below.

```
XYChart.Series<String ,Number> series=new XYChart.Series<>();
series.setName("Kcal");
series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Monday",2700));
series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Tuesday",2400));
series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Wednesday",3100)); 
chart_kcal.getData().add(series);
```

[image]

Comment: Also consider [tag:jfreechart-fx], which offers a variety of annotations, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46230815/230513).

Comment: So there isn't any way to make it on Bar Chart builded in Scene Builder?

Comment: I think I stacked a linechart on top of a barchart to achieve something like the is once. But I did don't allow the charts to be resized and I made sure the axis, lengths, and widths were identical.